# I have to press reset button twice for ubuntu to reboot

Tags: restart

The button in the taskbar. I click it once to restart and the system acts like nothing happened (I do see steam system tray close). Then once I click it again, it immediately reboots.

I have steam, Private Internet access, keepass, and nextcloud, running in the background. Not sure what else I need to provide to help troubleshoot.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I have to click twice on the "sleep" button - I am curios if there is the same underlying problem.

Comment: I do not have a taskbar in standard Ubuntu 19.10. So please indicate the desktop environment you use, and clarify a bit more what you do to access the function.

Comment: Gnome. Ubuntu ships with gnome. If it was xfce it would be xubuntu, Plasma Kubuntu, etc. I thought it was self-implied. https://imgur.com/jwadUf9 it's the button in the upper right.

Comment: GNOME 3.x does not include a taskbar by default; it has a panel (or more correctly '*top bar*', see https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html.en, https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-introduction.html.en) & dock (strictly 'activities') in Ubuntu, though I think the issue is the use of terms that apply to non-GNOME desktops as if they apply to gnome. Is it the '**top bar**' you are asking about?

Comment: Yes I suppose it is the top bar/top panel since that's where the power button is. It's the power button that I have to click twice. Whether for sleep, shutdown, or restart. And it doesn't happen every time. Any log I can pull that may show what is preventing it from shutting down/restarting/sleeping?

Comment: @jugmac00 What (if any) gnome extensions do you have installed? Have any non default theme installed and in use?

Comment: @BingBong MConnect, Ubuntu AppIndicators and Ubuntu Dock - no extra theme